# XRM: XML relational mapping

Tags: c#, .net, xml, relational-database

A Dynamic Entity designer, The custom entity created in runtime by admin user. I wont store all entities' data in a single table or xml field. Each entity must have specific table.

I found out that I should use weakly type for implementing dynamic entity I chose xml as weakly type.

I need a .net open source tool that it maps **relational database table to xml document and vice versa**.

Something like ORM that maps relational table to object, Here Something that maps relational table to xml

Comment: How is the admin user creating in runtime? Is he putting these items in a database or is he inputting them to the program which should store them in classes? I'd like to help, but need more detail.

Comment: we don't want to use class and any type of strongly types.
if we use strongly types we will have to use runtime generating class and object and reflecting and ...
but those are complicated by low performance and low runtime speed.
we must use weakly type like xml,key/value collection or other types those are very dynamic but a little hard to code.
in a dynamic program I hate strongly types because those are very cumbersome.
-- I think your question about "how is he creating in runtime an entity" has been resolved but if my explantion is not enough I am here to exlapain more :)